# Typescript overloading an HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement an overloaded HOC, the interface looks like this:

```
interface FallbackProps {
    error: Error;
    resetErrorBoundary: (...args: Array<unknown>) => void;
}

type Hoc<P> = {
    (fallback: ComponentType<FallbackProps>): (
        WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>,
    ) => (props: P) => JSX.Element;

    (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>): (props: P) => JSX.Element;
};
```

Which can be called like this:

```
hoc(Component);
hoc(({ error }) => <div>custom error fallback</div>)(Component);
```

Comment: Could you explain more what issues are you facing and what is not working as expected?

Comment: I couldn't implement the function itself. @mddg